# What's wrong with the Maxwell demon? Seems very trivial consequence of the second law of Thermodynamics...?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

**Maxwell Demon's Paradom:** The entropy production of the system $X$ becomes negative:
$$\Delta S(X) + Q_X \leq 0$$

**Exorcism of the demon:**
I believe that this paradox has been resolved by an inequalities of the following form (1) and (2), proposed in slightly different forms by many literatures around 2010.

$$\Delta S(X) + Q_X \geq -I(X;Y)\tag1$$
or generally,
$$\Delta S(X) + Q_X \geq \Delta I(X;Y),\tag2$$
where $X$ is the target system's state and $Y$ is the memory's state of the demon. $S$ , $I$ and $Q_X$ is entropy, mutual information and heat emission from the system $X$, respectively. We denote by $\Delta A$ the production of $A$ in the time step, such as $\Delta S(X) = S(X^\prime) - S(X)$.

For example, for (1), see the main result of [1] and for (2), see the inequality (2) in [2].

[1] Sagawa, Takahiro, and Masahito Ueda. "Generalized Jarzynski equality under nonequilibrium feedback control." Physical review letters 104.9 (2010): 090602.

[2] Ito, Sosuke, and Takahiro Sagawa. "Information thermodynamics on causal networks." Physical review letters 111.18 (2013): 180603.

**Question:** Aren't the equalities (1) and (2) a very very straightforward consequence of the second law of thermodynamics *under the assumption that thermodynamic entropy and Shannon entropy can be equated*？

Why is the derivation of these inequalities an important result? Was solving the paradox so difficult problem? Why?

**Background:**
I don't feel that the Maxwell demon is a paradox at all. I think it can be solved by very elementary arithmetic, as long as we accept the assumption that thermodynamic entropy and Shannon entropy can be equated in the framework of stochastic thermodynamics. In fact, I believe that a series of very similar papers published since around 2010 all essentially take the following approach.

**Derivation:**
Consider a classical two-body system $X$ and $Y$ in contact with a heat bath. We set $k_B T = 1$. $X$ and $Y$ develop to $X^\prime$ and $Y^\prime$.
By the second law of Thermodynamics (SLT), the following holds.

$$\Delta S(X,Y) + Q_{X,Y} \geq 0\tag3$$

By a famous property of mutual information,

$$\Delta S(X,Y) = \Delta S(X) + \Delta S(Y) - \Delta I(X;Y)\tag4$$

Here, we use the assumption that thermodynamics entropy is the same quantity of Shannon entropy except the unit. (See the paper [3])

[3] "Parrondo, J., Horowitz, J. & Sagawa, T. Thermodynamics of information. Nature Phys 11, 131–139 (2015)."

By combining (3) and (4), we obtains the inequality (2) if we ignore the heat emission from $Y$ ($Q_{Y}=0$).

**Interpretation:** Let me compare our setting with usual Maxwell demon's setting. The random variable $X$ takes a binary value representing whether an approaching particle is hot or cold. The random variable $Y$ denotes the state of the controller's (demon's) memory, which also takes binary.

**Appendix:** I know that the researchers have derived so-called detailed-fluctuation-theorem-style relation in stead of inequalities (1) and (2). However, I think the derivations are essentially the same of the above one.

Comment: Maxwell demon is a resolved paradox. I suggest that you add your description of the paradox before discussing it, as it seems that you do not differentiate between the paradox itself and its solution - not in teh way it is usually done at least. Also, thermodynamic entropy is not the same as the Boltzmann entropy and not the same as the ifnormation entropy. In fact, Jaynes claims that there are six different things that pass under the same name.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thank you for your comment! I added the description of the paradox. I think many papers including [1] assumes that "the Shannon entropy, multiplied by Boltzmann’s constant, as a candidate for non-equilibrium entropy". Please let me know if there is a study  that resolves the paradox without this assumption.

Comment: I am not a person asserting "I solved the paradox!" I just want to know whether this is really difficult problem or not, and the reason why.

Comment: It still seems to me somewhat abstract, compared to what is usually understood by [Maxwell demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon) I suggest that you define all teh quantities in terms of the usual description. The solution of the paradox, as I understand it, is that the demon controlling the door/lid is itself not deterministic - you seem to take it for granted.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thanks! I added `interpretation' section in the question. I wish this is enough to define our problem correctly.

Comment: For me the issue is that you somehow assume the solution of the paradox to show that there is no paradox. If you connect from the beginning the information entropy to the thermodynamic entropy then there is no longer a paradox. If you think in term of XIX century thermodynamic the relation with mutual information cannot be used as it is a concern of information theory.

Comment: @StarBucK Thank you! I agree with you. I think the difficulty was in creating a framework for equating thermodynamic entropy with Shannon entropy.  Stochastic thermodynamics, which provided that framework, appeared around 2005 [Seifert], so I feel that the authors of the paper that exorcised Demon around 2010 were born at the right time, rather than having solved a difficult problem.
[Seifert] Seifert, Udo. "Entropy production along a stochastic trajectory and an integral fluctuation theorem." Physical review letters 95.4 (2005): 040602.

Comment: The question here remains unclear. Maxwell's demon was a long-standing paradox, eventually resolved in 1982 by Bennett after many decades of discussion and research in the community. Modern understanding of the connection between information and thermodynamic entropy changes (they are **not** the same in general --- e.g. see [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.07668) for a primer) allows one to represent and solve the problem using simple algebra. What sort of mathematics would you deem to make the problem "non-trivial"? What has this to do with physics? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello, @MarkMitchison ! Thank you for your comment. Please see "derivation" section in the question to see how easy the math is to derive the second-law-like inequalities incorporating information. Yes, the relation between thermodynamic entropy and Shannon entropy is delicate issue. However, I believe the authors in Refs [1-3] **assume** that those entropies are equivalent without unit. So my question is the first sentence in the "question" section, which is updated slightly.

Comment: Yes the equalities are straightforward consequences of stochastic thermodynamcs, as you have already shown ([NB. one does not need to assume that thermodynamic and information entropies are the same to show this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5165)). The paradox was a difficult problem because it was posed and solved long before stochastic thermodynamics was formulated. I guess the starting point of your question is the idea that the paradox was solved only in 2010? (a historical characterisation that most physicists would not agree with)

Comment: @MarkMitchison Yes, it is. For example, PRL published Ref. [1], but I can not understand why this result is so outstanding deserving to be published in the top journal  because I feel this is a straightforward result of stochastic thermodynamics (and the calculation technique to derive the detailed fluctuation theorem, which is also easy.)

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thank you for your reference. I would read later carefully. I am very interested in your comment "a historical characterisation that most physicists would not agree with". AFAIK, most of recent studies of the exorcism of the demon cited papers after around 2008. Probably I missed some papers. Please let me know some references.

Comment: @MarkMitchison AFAIK, Maruyama et al "Colloquium: The physics of Maxwell’s demon and information." is a classic of the review paper of the paradox. I think the solution appeared there is essentially the same as a way using inequalities (1) and (2) shown in my question. I think researchers also regard Benett's solution using Landauer's principle as a resolution of the paradox. However, he did not show the second-law-like inequality. So, it is out of the scope in this question.

Comment: I'm probably making a silly mistake here, but it seems to me that if you start by assuming the second law holds, then there is no paradox to begin with. The problem is to show that the demon must respect the second law *without* assuming as much.

Comment: @d_b Thank you very much for your comment. I totally agree with you. The modern resolution shown in Ref [1] assumes local detailed balance, and I think the local detailed balance condition implies the second law by fluctuation theorem. So,  Ref. [1]  assumed the second law as you mentioned. That's why it seems to me that the modern resolution of the paradox such as [1] is a very straightforward observation.

Comment: @LightYagmi Ah, I see your point now.